# annotations on entites with same superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphism, hibernate-annotations

Consider two entites with the same superclass

```
@Entity
public class EntityA extends MyEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "int_calc_id")
    private Calculation calculation;

}

@Entity
public class EntityB extends MyEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "calculation_id")
    private Integer calculationId;

}
```

`Calculation` is an entity corresponding to the calculationId. So my first refactoring would be to use the class in both entities. My question is: Can I shift the calculation to `MyEntity`?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class EntityA extends MyEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "int_calc_id")
    private Calculation calculation;

}

public class EntityB extends MyEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "int_calc_id")
    private Calculation calculation;

}
```